# Entity Framework Unit of Work pattern object lifetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-of-work, entity-framework-5

I'm using MVC + Entity Framework 5 and currently looking at the [Unit of Work pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). In a controller class I see the following code:

```
private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
```

Does this mean that for every controller the `UnitOfWork` class is created, resulting in a database connection per `UnitOfWork` instance? Or do all `DbContext` instances (in this article `SchoolContext` instances which are created in `UnitOfWork`) share the same connection?

My second question: would it improve the performance of the application when only one `UnitOfWork` instance is created which is stored in the `HttpContext`, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me caution you.  I know you aren't doing this, but I want to make sure you understand that you should never ever ever create a single data context and make it a static or singleton.  The reason is that statics are shared between all instances of the app (ie multiple users) and data contexts are not multi-thread or multi-user safe.

Having given that warning, let's move on.

In general, you don't have to worry about this.  The reason is that even though you create multiple UnitOfWorks, only one controller will ever be active at a time (per web request).  Entity Framework has a connection pooler that reuses connections and optimizes their use.  (actually, this is part of Ado.net, but it still applies)

Comment: Thanks! I read about the `HttpContex` storage approach on a blog, is that similar to the singleton pattern meaning it's wrong as well?

Comment: @Marthijn - No, there's nothing "wrong" about it, but I don't usually see a need for it, except in certain rare situations.  HttpContexts also only exist for a single request, so if you add a context to the request, it will get destroyed after the request is over (although you should manually dispose of it in the Application_EndRequest event).  I don't see any gain from using this technique.

Comment: Storing your unit of work in the Request is something I've done for a few years and had success on sites doing considerably large amounts of traffic (million+ pgs a day). I was at first worried about connection limits, but as `Myster Man` says EF and ADO do some dark voodoo to keep the pool ticking along.

Comment: @Doug - I prefer to use Dependency Injection rather than the HttpContext, this allows you to create a single context per request and not worry about having global data.

Comment: @MystereMan this is actually what i was referring to. creating a wrapper for HttpContext.Items (ie an HttpContextBaseDbContextStore). HttpContex.Items only lives for the life time of a request so can easily hold the unit of work for your requests lifetime. As I mentioned I was at first concerned on a "per request" context, as large traffic may flood your DB server, but in practice EF and ADO take care of this pretty well.